# Maximo Anywhere 7.6 - Adding additional field to a list item - Error: Cannot add an item to layout

Tags: maximo-anywhere

We are trying to add a field in the SR List screen of Service Request app. We are able to see the additional field's data in the response and see the value in the detail screen. But the same is not visible in the list screen even after we made changes in the WorkListItem.xml. When we looked at the developer logs, we saw an error as below.

Cannot add an item to layout [generated_application_ui_layout_small_WorkListItem_0]. Position [item7] does not exist.

We executed build.xml and also artifact-processor.xml. But if is of no use as we are still getting the error.

Below are code snippets added in the app.xml & WorkListItem.xml.

app.xml

```
<listItemTemplate     id="ServiceRequest.MyReportedSR_serviceRequest_listItemTemplate_WorkListItem"     layout="WorkListItem">
.
.
<listtext id="ServiceRequest.MyReportedSR_serviceRequest_WorkListItem_internalpriority" layoutInsertAt="item7" resourceAttribute="internalpriority"/>

</listItemTemplate>
```

WorkListItem.xml

```
<layout>
.
.
  <row id="row_3">
    <column colspan="10" columnid="item7" id="item7_column"/>
  </row>
</layout>
```

Please let us know if we are missing any steps.

Regards,
Karthik

Comment: its strange try change the colspan place <column columnid="item7"  colspan="10"  id="item7_column" />
you did full Build ?? build-all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the standard Service Requests app has issue when it is referring the Worklistitem layout xml. I have found that there is field mapped to item2 in app.xml but item2 is not present in the layout xml.

I have created a custom layout file copied from the WorkListItem and provided a different name. It worked after referring the new layout xml which included item2(*For existing field*) and item7 (*New Field which we wanted to display*) added in the layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

The layoutInsertAt field should point to the id within the layout which is id="item7_column", not "item7".

Comment: I tried changing the id but it didn't work. And all the standard fields are referred in the same way and I have followed the same.
For Eg: 
`<listtext id="ServiceRequest.MyReportedSR_serviceRequest_WorkListItem_description" layoutInsertAt="item3" resourceAttribute="summary"/>`

Strange thing is the generated WorkListItem.js (_./common/js/generated/application/ui/layout/small_ folder) file for this layout doesn't have the new field added in the WorkListItem.xml. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Yes, this is because you have to "touch" the app.xml file in the artifacts directory to get the application to rebuild itself after you make a layout file change.  We have improved this in our next release so we will detect these layout file changes and cause the application to correctly be regenerated without requiring you to touch the app.xml file.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like some issue in the Service Request app as the WorklistItem template xml is being referred from a different app. I have created a custom layout and assigned it to the Reported SR list and it worked.